# Cannot reference VisibleSlicerItemsList for regular pivot table in VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, olap, vba

I am trying to manipulate a slicer for a regular Pivot table in VBA (not PowerPivot), but I cannot reference the VisibleSlicerItemsList. I get an error:

> Application-defined or object-defined error

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[Screenshot showing data and pivot table with slicer from test workbook, along with the error message "Application-defined or object-defined error" for the VisibleSlicerItemsList in the Locals window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx369.png)

You can download the test workbook [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97140783/Test%20wkb.xlsx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193916.aspx) entry on this property - it states that:

> The **VisibleSlicerItemsList** property is only applicable for slicers that are based on OLAP data sources (SlicerCache.OLAP = True).

In your example you are using a pivot table connected to data in the sheet and not to an OLAP cube.

You can work around it with code like this which iterates the `SlicerItems` collection of the `SlicerCache`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim objCache As SlicerCache
    Dim objItem As SlicerItem
    Dim varChoices As Variant
    Dim lngCounter1 As Long
    Dim lngCounter2 As Long

    Set objCache = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Company")
    varChoices = Array("1", "3", "5")

    ' iterate slicers
    For lngCounter1 = 1 To objCache.SlicerItems.Count
        Set objItem = objCache.SlicerItems(lngCounter1)
        'assume not for selection
        objItem.Selected = False
        'iterate choices to check for activation
        For lngCounter2 = 0 To UBound(varChoices)
            If objItem.Name = varChoices(lngCounter2) Then
                'activate and exit loop
                objItem.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngCounter2
    Next lngCounter1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Robin, this answers my question. There is an old KB article that explaines the difference between OLAP and non-OLAP PivotTables here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/234700

Comment: Thanks - if you feel my answer helped, then feel free to accept the answer with the green tick next to the answer. Cheers.